# Appropriate to use Futures and Promises for delayed initialization?

Tags: scala, akka, promise, future

Is it appropriate to use Futures and Promises for delayed initialization, rather than using an Option var or some mutable variable?

You could create a factory class that encapsulates the promise:

```
class IntFactory{
  val intPromise = Promise[Int]
  def create () : Future[Int] = intPromise.future
  def init (data : String) : Unit = intPromise success data.length
}
```

An actor or some other class could then use it like this:

```
class MyActor(factory : IntFactory) extends Actor{
  val future_int = factory.create()

  def receive = {
    case (msg : String) => factory.init(msg) // Now the promise is fulfilled  
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing something like this? It may not have been ideal to use an actor as an example, as I think there are better alternatives for actors (become or FSM). I am currently considering using this with a non-actor class. Some of the instance variables are nothing until certain events occur.  I was considering doing this instead of using a var Option and setting it to None. If this is bad, what are some other alternatives?

**EDIT:**

I thought of situations where this might be more useful. If I had multiple things that needed to be initialized, and I had some async action that I wanted to perform when it was all done:

```
class MyActor(factory1 : IntFactory, factory2 : IntFactory) extends Actor{
  val future_int1 = factory1.create()
  val future_int2 = factory2.create()

  for{
    x <- future_int1
    y <- future_int2
  } // Do some stuff when both are complete

  def receive = {
    case "first" => factory1.init("first") 
    case "second" => factory2.init("second") 
  }
}
```

Then I would not have to check which ones are None every time I get another piece.

**MORE EDITS:**

Some additional information that I failed to specify in my original question:

1. The data needed to initialize the objects will come in asynchronously.
2. The data passed to the init function is required for initialization. I edited my example code so that this is now the case.
3. I am not using Akka. I thought Akka would be helpful for throwing together a quick example and thought that experienced Akka people could provide useful feedback.

Comment: This is a good read on the builder pattern - used when something is initialized a piece at a time, I've never used it but what's cool is that it can be accomplished before runtime - so you get a compiler error if you try to access something too early: http://nullary.blogspot.com/2011/10/builder-pattern-revisited-in-scala.html

Comment: Wouldn't just `lazy val` be sufficient?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Could you rework the example using a lazy val?  I don't know how I would do this. I'm not sure it would work because my initialization depends on data from an outside async event.

Comment: @LaloInDublin That was a very interesting article (I read the Rafael rambling one).  However, I don't see how this could be used in an async case. Please correct me and give an example if I am wrong. In my original question, I did not make it clear that the data I need is coming in asynchronously. I am editing my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly a better approach than using mutable variables (whether `Option` or not). Using `lazy val`, as @PatrykĆwiek suggested, is even better if you can initialize the state at any time instead of waiting for external events and don't need to do it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your `IntFactory`, you don't really need the `data` string (it's not used anywhere), so I *think* the base case could be rewritten like this:

```
class Foo {
  lazy val first = {
    Thread.sleep(2000) // Some computation, initialization etc.
    25
  }
  lazy val second = {
    Thread.sleep(1000) // Some computation, initialization etc.
    11
  }
  def receive(s : String) = s match {
    case "first" => first
    case "second" => second
    case _ => -1
  }
}
```

now, let's say you do this:

```
val foo = new Foo()
println(foo.receive("first"))  // waiting for 2 seconds, initializing
println(foo.receive("first"))  // returns immediately
println(foo.receive("second")) // waiting for 1 second, initializing
```

Now both `first` and `second` can be initialized *at most once*.

You can't pass parameters to `lazy val`s, so if the `data` string is somehow important to the initialization, then you'd probably be better off using factory method with memoization (IMO).

Comment: When I actually used this, the input to the init was needed. My example was not super clear about this. I was trying to simplify the example as much as possible and went a bit too far. I will investigate factory method with memoization.